# Javascript, Html: function executing after completion of click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I have an anchor tag like:

```
<a href="#actions" data-toggle="tab">Actions</a>
```

There is a click function for the above `anchor` tag:

```
$('a[href="#actions"]').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
    show_overlay_loading($("body"), "Loading actions tab...");
    // some stuff runs (takes about 5 secs)
    remove_overlay_loading();
});
```

As you can see, the above function takes about 5 secs to complete. So, I called the function `show_overlay_loading` at the beginning of click function. It adds a loading spinner to the body.

After the rest of the code completes, I removed the spinner by calling `remove_overlay_loading` at the bottom of the click function.

The two functions are below:

```
var show_overlay_loading = function(element, helper_text){
    var overlay_div = document.createElement("div");
    overlay_div.className = "overlay-div-cont";
    var overlay_html = `
        <div class="overlay-img-cont">
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" class="overlay_image_gif">
            <span class="overlay_helper_text">${helper_text}</span>
        </div>
    `
            `
    overlay_div.innerHTML = overlay_html;
    element.append(overlay_div);
}

var remove_overlay_loading = function(element){
    $(".overlay-div-cont").remove();  
}
```

As you can see, the `show_overlay_loading` function creates a overlay div and appends it the element passed (in this case, it's body)The `remove_overlay_loading` simply removes the div.

The problem is, when i click, the spinner is not getting added to body. But when i debug, it's getting added.

**Possible cause**: the spinner is not getting added because, though function is running, it is appending the element after some time. But by that time, we remove the spinner by calling `remove_overlay_loading`. (It's just my view, idk if it's correct.)

I arrived at the above cause by modifying the `remove_overlay_loading` to the following:

```
var remove_overlay_loading = function(element){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".overlay-div-cont").remove();
    }, 10000)
}
```

After modifying `remove_overlay_loading` to above, the spinner is displayed but after the full click function got completed. The spinner got removed after the `timeout`.

Note: The `show_overlay_spinner` and `remove_overlay_spinner` are being called only once in the whole code and that is inside click function.

Note: It's working in firefox but not in chrome

Comment: You're going to have to do a timeout after displaying the spinner so that it shows when you want it.  This means that the code that follows the show_over_lay_spinner needs to be placed in a callback function so that it gets called after the spinner shows.   Remember, javascript functions are not truly multitasking, which means that you have to break their execution flow when you want something to show before the end of a function, so that the display happens, but the callback function starts a fraction of a second later and performs the rest of the things you also want to occur.

Comment: What on earth takes *5 seconds* to execute that's not asynchronous?